# How can I check if the user has input one or two values?

Tags: java, user-input

I am writing a program where the user can input up to two values, so if the user inputs one value, it calls the first constructor and if the user inputs 2 values the second constructor is called, but the issue is when the user inputs one value and press enter, the program will be waiting for the second value.

Basically, I want the program to execute the function based on the number of inputs. Also, I can't ask the user how many inputs he wants to add before either.

Basically, I'm trying to see if writing java ValuM 5 or java ValuM 5 6  in the command line and get the right function executed.

Someone said it to use the timer Class, to put it in a timeout, but I'm not sure how it works, or if there is an easier way to do this.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
public class ValueM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first_Input=myObj.nextInt();
        int Second_Input=myObj.nextInt();
    
        ValueM array_gen=new ValueM(first_Input);
        array_gen=new ValueM(Second_Input,first_Input);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between the user thinking about what the second input should be and the user deciding not to enter a second value? Unless you develop some mind-reading technology, I'm afraid you'll have to give them some active choice (like ask "want to enter a second value" or something like that).

Comment: Also note that your question and problem have *nothing* to do with the Java compiler.

Comment: Yup.  The compiler doesn't execute anything!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to require the user to enter both numbers *on the same line*. That way you could use `myObj.nextLine()` and check if it contains one or two numbers. (I would rename `myObj` to `scanner` or something similar.)

To check if the line contains one or two numbers, you could create a second `Scanner` with the line as the source: `Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);`, then use `lineScanner.nextInt()` to read the first number and `lineScanner.hasNextInt()` to check if there is a second one.

Answer (score 1):

Your input values look like command line arguments so you don't need to use Scanner. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ValueM array_gen;
    if (args.length == 1) {
        array_gen=new ValueM(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    } else if (args.length == 2) {
        array_gen=new ValueM(Integer.parseInt(args[1]),Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    } else {
        // message user about bad input
    }
}
```